# Using Powershell, how can I change filename recursively in a way to replace '0' with '-' in specific part of file name?

Tags: regex, powershell, recursion

**Directory Structure:**

```
C:\C4144754951436B4\RECORDS\7005\2017\12\20\1000\1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav
```

Files exist only in last folder (1000 in the above case)

**Current File Name**

```
1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav
```

**Required File Name**

I need to replace any `0` after last `#` with `-` so that result becomes:

```
1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz-Bin-Mah.Sid-Asr.wav
```

I tried but couldn't make it work with a single liner, recursively.

```
PS H:\> $test

1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav

PS H:\> $ol=($test -split "#")[0]+'#'+($test -split "#")[1]+'#'+($test -split "#")[2]+'#'+($test -split "#")[3]+'#'+($te
st -split "#")[4].replace('0','-')

PS H:\> $ol

1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz-Bin-Mah.Sid-Asr.wav
```

How can I achieve the same results using `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: I believe `split("#")[-1].replace("0", "-")` will work.

Comment: Only partly, you will only get the part of the last # with that approach

Comment: @Ingemar it was just to display how to do the last part, but I've added it to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47908969/3600709)

Comment: Right. It's a matter of taste which solution you go for. I know which one I prefer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$FullName = 'C:\C4144754951436B4\RECORDS\7005\2017\12\20\1000\1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav'
$NewFullName = $FullName.Substring(0, $FullName.LastIndexOf('#')) + $FullName.Substring($FullName.LastIndexOf('#')).Replace('0','-')
```

If you want it in a pipeline with `Rename-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object {
        $_.Name.LastIndexOf('#') -ge 0;
    } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $NewName = $_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.LastIndexOf('#')) + $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.LastIndexOf('#')).Replace('0','-');
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName;
    }
```

The `Where-Object` is necessary because `Substring` requires positive arguments and if the `#` character isn't present, then `LastIndexOf` returns -1.

I suppose you can condense it to:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -File | 
    Where-Object {
        $_.Name.LastIndexOf('#') -ge 0;
    } |
    Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name.Substring(0, $_.Name.LastIndexOf('#')) + $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.LastIndexOf('#')).Replace('0','-'));
```

But I find that much harder to read.

Comment: I preferred single liner + recursive and your reply serves the purpose best, tested in my test platform. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions will solve your problem. Not a one-liner though :)

```
$currentFileName = '1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav'
$currentFileName -match '(.*#)(.*)'
$newFileName = $Matches[1] + $Matches[2].Replace('0', '-')

$currentFileName, $newFileName
```

Will output

```
1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav
1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz-Bin-Mah.Sid-Asr.wav
```

Comment: I never pass on the chance to use one of my favorite quotes: ***"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."*** - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Which by the way is not intended to diminish the use of Regexes in this solution. I just like the quote.

Comment: Indeed. Randall is a genius (and I use that term in the literal sense) and XKCD is far and away my favorite comic.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##LY1Ni8IwFEX3/oqQdFEZW17SF4uCC62CwojQLmYxcRE1MwZKLU38wD/faXXu4l44XDj15W4adzZl2baB8w2ZEZpNVYYcMZU4kRyT8QJVvsp2@bJQKYBUAniquOhWcYCuRIKsh1wIYONEThCRgYT/sK3WT1jYCrb6HBf2BHPXxHd9o4NAd8ZeHBfXQze2@g1h9Caf2vlNdTKP3U9IGR2SD8L7et/r0voX/o74Ps5NXeqjCSnQEaERHQ6@GutNtL44TwLdtn8)

```
$str = "C:\C4144754951436B4\RECORDS\7005\2017\12\20\1000\1234#20171220#6359444#0500000000#Maaz0Bin0Mah.Sid0Asr.wav"
$a = $str.Substring(0, $str.LastIndexOf("#") + 1) + $str.Split("#")[-1].Replace("0", "-")
Write-Host $a
```

---

### Explanation

The code is:

1. Removing everything after the last occurrence of `#`
2. Splitting the original string on `#`, getting the last element, then replacing all instances of `0` with `-`
3. Concatenating `1.` and `2.` above